# Proper way to make a dynamic navigation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm building my first Laravel application using 5.1, it's an ecommerce site.

I've started by creating the "static" pages. I quote because the pages are not dynamically generated from product lists etc, but the html is still retrieved from the database.

I've created a `PagesController`, a `Page` model, the `pages/index.blade.php` and `pages/show.blade.php` views, as well as a `MasterTemplate.blade.php` template file.

My `routes.php` looks like:

```
$router->get('/', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@index',
    'as' => 'pages.index'
]);

$router->get('/{page}', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@show',
    'as' => 'pages.show'
]);
```

This works fine, I can view my index and individual pages that are in the DB.

My problem occurs when I go to add my navigation. Since I plan on using two different navigation bars (one for user, one for admins), I opted to create a `_navDefault.php` file to include in the `MasterTemplate`.

Stripping out the excess html it looks like:

```
@foreach ($pages as $page)
    <li>{!! link_to_route('pages.show', $page->title, [$page->slug]) !!}</li>
@endforeach
```

This generates the links just fine and they work. But because my `PagesController`:

```
...
public function index()
{
    $pages = $this->page->get();
    return view('pages.index', compact('pages'));
}
...
```

`$pages` only exists on the `index` view, and so navigating to a `show` view gives me an error that `$pages` is undefined, which makes perfect sense.

I could define `$pages` in the `show` method, but I will also have other controllers such as `ProductController` and `CartController` that will have their own pages I will need in the navigation bar, and I can't very well include `$pages`, `$products`, and `$cart` in every `index` and `show` method for each controller.

I'm still fairly new to MVC so I'm not sure of the best way to handle this, with a nav controller/model or something else.

What is the proper way to achieve dynamic navigation bars using multiple controllers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I'm able to have my dynamic navbar everywhere in my app.

Test the following within the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('pages', Page::all());
});
```

The `*` means all *views* will receive `$pages`.

You can now extract it to a Service Provider dedicated to view composers.

Comment: beyond just adding that to the boot function. can you expand on "You can now extract it to a Service Provider dedicated to view composers."

Comment: Nowadays the approach is available in the official docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question right, you need to create a partial view for your navigation and use a view composer to make sure that partial view has the proper data.

[docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 1):

[edit] It is my project and I am always available for its contribution on github.

A perfect-for-your-issue Laravel 5.4 Supported Package for Creating Dynamic, Database Driven, Bootstrap supported, Drop Down Menu is available.

https://github.com/secrethash/dropmenu

Install it using:

`composer require secrethash/dropmenu`

Usage:

```
use Dropmenu;

class SampleController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
            $menu = Dropmenu:: display('menuName');

            return view('some.view', ['menu' => $menu]);
    }
}
```

OR simply use it in the blade template

```
@extends('demoLayout')

@section('menu')
    {!! Dropmenu:: display('menuName') !!}
@endsection
```

Full Documentation: https://secrethash.github.io/dropmenu

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing a directory and/or a subdomain that is the same as your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site. If you do so, you need to disclose that it's your site. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's often considered spam.  See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).